# Microsoft Access Turn off Filter and stay on record

Tags: filter, ms-access-2010

Currently, I have a behavior implemented which allows my MS Acess DB to go to a specific record in another subform.   However, this leaves the filter on, and when I turn off the filter the subform returns back to the first entry in the overall set. Is there a way I can navigate to this record, then turn off the filter but stay at the record I found?

I've been trying to pop VBA code into on enter or on click but I can't seem to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the primary key of your subform to navigate back to the record. Put a command button on your form and in the event procedure of the button do something like this:

```
Dim ID as Variant

With [SubForm].Form
  ID=!PrimaryKey.Value
  .FilterOn = False
  .Recordset.FindFirst "[ID]=" & ID
End With
```

That should get you in the ball park.

Comment: thanks a ton this really helped, I was stuck on doing something similar to that for the past few days.  I guess as a follow up question I'm using this in conjunction with a DoCmd.gotoRecord , , acNext but at the boundaries there obviously are no further records, however I cant seem to write a proper if statement to switch the behavior from go to next record to return back to the first statement.    Right now I'm checking if ID= null but obviously thats not correct.

Comment: @imprz Look at the BOF and EOF properties of the Recordset object. When you're past the last record - or before the first - EOF and BOF will be set accordingly. I often wrap my recordset code in If Not rec.BOF and not rec.EOF then... to catch instances where there are no records found.